# Loop through all columns of dataframe to plot scatter plot for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

My dataframe has 6 columns, I would like to plot scatter plot for each column against other columns, is there way to loop through all columns of dataframe to plot scatter plot rather than manually selecting x and y ?

Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 6), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
df.head()

# I don't want to manually select x and y instead, I am looking for automatically selecting one columns with another column

df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='b', color='r')    
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='c', color='r')    
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='d', color='r')   
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='e', color='r')   
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='a', y='f', color='r')
```

Comment: Are you actually looking for this? https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can iterate over columns like this

```py
for column in df:
    print(df[column])
```

Comment: How to select x and y while looping ?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you should do something like this:
for column1 in df:
   for column2 in df:
      df.plot(kind='scatter', x=column1, y=column2, color='r')

Comment: Here is example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gCoro2zX0wcDvkHsPwJf_30nMQUNHvE0?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for

Comment: Awesome, if you found my answer useful you can upvote and approve it :)